# how to delete nodes from redis cluster?

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

I google it and found two solution:

1. `CLUSTER FORGET` (http://redis.io/commands/cluster-forget)
2. `redis-trib.rb del-node`

I think `CLUSTER FORGET`" is the right way to do.

But I really want to know the details about `redis-trib.rb del-node`.

Can someone explain the difference between them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`redis-trib.rb` is a ruby utility script that antirez (lead redis developer) built as a reference implementation of building administrative tools on top of the basic redis cluster commands.

Under the hood redis-trib uses `CLUSTER FORGET` to implement it's own administrative del-node command. https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/unstable/src/redis-trib.rb#L1374

Redis-trib is a lot friendlier to work with. If you're doing `CLUSTER FORGET` you'd need to loop over and send that command to every other node in the system, while del-node will automate that process for you.

Answer (score 3):

### **As of Redis 6.2.3**

***WARNING***: redis-trib.rb is not longer available!
You should use redis-cli instead.

All commands and features belonging to redis-trib.rb have been moved
to redis-cli.
In order to use them you should call `redis-cli` with the `--cluster`
option followed by the subcommand name, arguments and options.

Use the following syntax:
`redis-cli --cluster SUBCOMMAND [ARGUMENTS] [OPTIONS]`

Example:
`redis-cli --cluster info 127.0.0.1:6382`

---

```
~$ redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> CLUSTER HELP
127.0.0.1:6379> CLUSTER NODES
127.0.0.1:6379> CLUSTER FORGET <node-id>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
src/redis-trib.rb del-node 192.168.0.211:6379 650e3746968e6b7c7e357f06adbde5b3b92fcceb
```

Note:

- `192.168.0.211:6379` This is any node in the cluster
- `650e3746968e6b7c7e357f06adbde5b3b92fcceb` this is the cluster ID of the node you want to remove. You can get the value of this ID from “cluster nodes” command.

Answer (score 0):

Per redis article you should use:

redis-cli --cluster del-node 127.0.0.1:7000

where the the first argument is one of your cluster nodes.

Check 'removing a node' in he following article:

https://redis.io/docs/manual/scaling/